# deactivate and activate a specific UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uilocalnotification

What do I have to do that I can cancel a specific UILocalNotification?

Comment: You posted a description of a complex goal, and a bunch of code. What, specifically, are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking a way to cancel specific local notification. If that is what you are looking for, this might help you.

The following is the code for cancelling a local notification.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotification]
```

For identifying the specific UILocalNotification if your notification is not global.

```
for (UILocalNotification *localNotification in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications])
{
    NSDictionary* userInfo = localNotification.userInfo;
    if ([[userInfo objectForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:@"NAME_OF_NOTIFICATION"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotification];
        break;
    }
}
```

Here, I used UILocalNotifications userinfo to identify the specific UILocalNotification. You can use other things like alertTitle etc. to identify different UILocalNotifications

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Is that the final code? So I just change the user info to my preferences and then put this code inside a function and call it whenever I need it?